# Unable to set up Redis in a Node.js project

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, node-redis

when using  `client.set('hi', 'there')`  , I was getting  `Uncaught ClientClosedError: The client is closed redis` , so I had to use:

`client.connect()`

It worked but then I was getting an unresolved promise, so I had to use  `await`:

`await client.set('hi', 'there')`

It then worked, but now when I am using  `client.hset('german', 'red', 'rot')` , I am getting:

`Uncaught TypeError: client.hset is not a function`

I am following a tutorial that did not mention the use of `client.connect()` nor `await` when using  `client.set('hi', 'there')`

Not sure if I installed the wrong version of Redis. I installed it using yarn because I was having issues with npm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In newer versions, Node-redis provides built-in support for all of the out-of-the-box Redis commands. They are exposed using the raw Redis command names (HSET, HGETALL, etc.) and a friendlier camel-cased version (hSet, hGetAll, etc.):

```
// raw Redis commands
await client.HSET('key', 'field', 'value');
await client.HGETALL('key');

// friendly JavaScript commands
await client.hSet('key', 'field', 'value');
await client.hGetAll('key');
```

More about this [here](https://github.com/redis/node-redis)

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I was using different versions of redis

Comment: This is not helpful. How did you solve it in newer version of Redis?

Comment: Post an answer when you figure it out

Comment: I have found answer in the meantime, and tested it. It works. I have just posted it.